# Getting uninitialized constant (NameError) inside decorators when running rspec tests via rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rake, decorator, rspec-rails

In my app I use an engine (blogit) to which I want to add some changes / behaviours.

I followed the guides on how to override engine controllers/models and added the following:

## The Code

In `config/initializer/blogit.rb`

```
# Requires extension ruby files in lib/blogit.
Dir[Rails.root.join("lib/blogit/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
```

In `lib/blogit/engine.rb`

```
module Blogit
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace Blogit

    config.to_prepare do
      Dir.glob(Rails.root + "app/decorators/**/blogit/*_decorator*.rb").each do |c|
        require_dependency(c)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In `app/decorators/controllers/blogit/comments_controller_decorator.rb`

```
Blogit::CommentsController.class_eval do
  def create
    Rails.logger.info "decorated controller action"
    # ... overridden stripped ...
  end
end
```

In `app/decorators/models/blogit/comment_decorator.rb`

```
Blogit::Comment.class_eval do
  belongs_to :user
end
```

To be mentioned:

- I have also created a migration to add a user reference to the comments model, since my app uses devise and I only want logged_in users to be able to comment. (Therefore I don't need the standard behaviour, so I'm going to override it.)

## The Problem

If I run `rake` I get the weird error:

```
/Users/Kassi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392-railsexpress/bin/ruby -S rspec ./spec/controllers/home_controller_spec.rb ./spec/models/user_spec.rb
/Users/Kassi/demo/app/decorators/controllers/blogit/comments_controller_decorator.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Blogit::CommentsController (NameError)
```

However, if I run the first line that rake mentions by hand (`.../ruby -S ...`), all tests are being run successfully.

In my project I'm using *guard* with *spork*. Running guard will also let the tests pass without any error.

The app itself runs fine, i.e. it starts without errors and I'm able to comment as I want. My decorator action code is being executed.

**So what's different when running *rake*?** 
**Why does it break?**

Note:

- Adding `require "blogit"` or `require "blogit/comments_controller"` doesn't help. It actually can't find the controller using *require*.

## A Demo Application

Since this problem is part of a bigger project, I created a new app from scratch for testing purposes that contains only the relevant stuff: basic rails app, rspec, devise, blogit and the decorators.
It can be found here: https://github.com/kassi/decorator_demo_rspec (git://github.com/kassi/decorator_demo_rspec.git)

Another repo using testunit (which is working!) can be found here: https://github.com/kassi/decorator_demo_testunit (git://github.com/kassi/decorator_demo_testunit.git)

Comment: Looks like an issue with rspec. I created a second demo repo using test unit (rails 3.2.14) where running tests using rake works perfectly: https://github.com/kassi/decorator_demo_testunit

Answer (score 0):

Instead of performing the require statements yourself, you can try [activesupport-decorators](https://github.com/pierre-pretorius/activesupport-decorators) that does it for you.